# Filter cells in google spreadsheet on wether they contain a , (comma)

Tags: google-sheets, filtering

I use the filter tool in google spreadsheets all the time to filter and sort data, but ive run into an issue with trying to filter data that contains a , (comma).

Ive tried to escape the character using `\,` or wrap it in quotes `','` but to no avail.. any ideas ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the filter controls, Filter by Condition > Text Contains > enter ","

[image]